# How to incorporate Stryker.NET tool in Azure DevOps pipelines in case of multiple project dependencies in a test project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mutation-testing, stryker, stryker-net

I have a unit test project file which depends on two other projects. `ABC.Service.UnitTest` is the test project and its dependencies are `XYZ.Service.csproj` and `LMN.Aggregator.csproj`.

In this case, what exactly do we need to have in our config file and how exactly can we incorporate this scenario into our ADO pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the project you want to mutation test using `-p` [option](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/configuration/#project-file-name):

```
dotnet stryker -p XYZ.Service.csproj
dotnet stryker -p LMN.Aggregator.csproj
```

Alternatively, you can use `project` config file option, though you'll need to have two config files then. Either way, this will produce two different reports in the two latest `StrykerOutput` folders.

What to do with this - depends on you. For example, you can attach these files to builds using the dedicated [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stryker-mutator.mutation-report-publisher), see the full guide [here](https://stryker-mutator.io/blog/azure-pipelines-integration/).